# Flask Gunicorn Multiple Users Problem Results

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

Hello Community members,
I have created an app in flask which is basically an openai model that takes voices and audio files for transcribing so i'm using gunicorn and when mulitple users try to upload and transcribe on the web app then it gives users resultls to another user or vice versa.

I tried to use the following configuration

- web: gunicorn main:app -k gevent --worker-connections 1000
- web: gunicorn main:app --workers 1 --threads 10 --timeout 100000
- web: gunicorn main:app --workers 10 --threads 10 --timeout 100000
- web: gunicorn main:app --workers 1 --threads 1 --timeout 100000
- web:gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --timeout 100000

and so on,
well i'm using railway.app for deploying the app and have taken developer plan which includes 8vCore CPU and 8GB Ram.

Can someone please help :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I created an ML app in the flask using Openai API and deployed it using railway.app but the problem is that if multiple users use that application, they get responses from each other. So how can I fix this problem?